# How to call static template-function of a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a replication of the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

template <typename T>
struct a_class {
    // build an a_class instance
    template <typename U>
    static a_class a_builder() {
        return a_class(sizeof(U));
    }

    // print out size
    void print() {
        printf("%zd\n", size_);
    }

private:
    a_class(ssize_t size) : size_(size) {}
    ssize_t size_;
};


template <typename T>
void some_func() {
    a_class<T> a = a_class<T>::a_builder<uint32_t>();
    a.print();
}


int main() {
    some_func();
}
```

Under g++ 7.3.0 I get this error:

```
 ╰─▸ g++ test.cc -o test
test.cc: In function ‘void some_func()’:
test.cc:26:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     a_class<T> a = a_class<T>::a_builder<uint32_t>();
                                                  ^
test.cc:26:52: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     a_class<T> a = a_class<T>::a_builder<uint32_t>();
                                                    ^
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:32:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘some_func()’
     some_func();
               ^
test.cc:25:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void some_func()
 void some_func() {
      ^~~~~~~~~
test.cc:25:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:32:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
     some_func();
               ^
```

Interestingly, if T is a concrete type:

```
void some_func() {
    a_class<int> a = a_class<int>::a_builder<uint32_t>();
    a.print();
}
```

Everything's fine.  Is there special syntax for this since it's a template context?

Comment: `a_class<T>::template a_builder<uint32_t>();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ouch, it's so obvious =D

Comment: Also `some_func();` needs to be `some_func<some_type>();`

Comment: Sometimes, trying another compiler helps. https://wandbox.org/permlink/z5pTcOi7l72s0b3q